# Converting a string into SendKeys.Send() formatted string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any smart and neat way to I guess escape characters in a `string` to make it compatible with the specific format the `SendKeys` uses?

At first I thought this would work:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\{{0}", "{{}");
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\}{0}", "{}}");
```

But this won't work work because it's doing two checks and messes up the syntax entirely.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Let's say I've got a string `class Abc { ...() { } }`. Now, the docummentation for `SendKeys.Send(str)` states that keys like `{` or `(` need to be enclosed in `{}` to be be read as an escaped keypress. How do I cleanly 'parse' a string to fit these criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some place holder instead of `{` and `}` and create the formatted result using those place holders. Then at last replace those place holders by `{` and `}`. For example:

```
string PrepareForSendKeys(string input)
{
    var specialChars = "+^%~(){}";
    var c1 = "[BRACEOPEN]";
    var c2 = "[BRACECLOSE]";
    specialChars.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        input = input.Replace(x.ToString(),
            string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", c1, x.ToString(), c2));
    });
    input = input.Replace(c1, "{");
    input = input.Replace(c2, "}");
    return input;
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
var input = "some string containing + ^ % ~ ( ) { }";
MessageBox.Show(PrepareForSendKeys(input));
```

And the result would be:

```
some string containing {+} {^} {%} {~} {(} {)} {{} {}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Something like that started forming in my mind but I wasn't sure how to approach this. Thanks again!